# PHP - Get Latitude & Longitude from an address

Tags: php, google-maps, google-geocoder

I have used the autocomplete of geocode but when I am selecting from the drop down it is giving me the lat and long of the address

I need to check when the lat and long are empty then from the posted address I must get the latitude and longitude

Comment: What's troubling you? Which part exactly do you need help with? (Also, see [Ask] for tips on asking better questions)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get longitude and latitude of any address?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3807963/how-to-get-longitude-and-latitude-of-any-address)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Suppose you have hidden value for lat and long is
mapLat & mapLong and input field name is location
then:

```
<html>
<form>
<input type="hidden" name="mapLat">
<input type="hidden" name="mapLong">
<input type="text" name="location">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
</html>



extract($_POST);
if($mapLat =='' && $mapLong ==''){
        // Get lat long from google
        $latlong    =   get_lat_long($location); // create a function with the name "get_lat_long" given as below
        $map        =   explode(',' ,$latlong);
        $mapLat         =   $map[0];
        $mapLong    =   $map[1];    
}


// function to get  the address
function get_lat_long($address){

    $address = str_replace(" ", "+", $address);

    $json = file_get_contents("http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=$address&sensor=false&region=$region");
    $json = json_decode($json);

    $lat = $json->{'results'}[0]->{'geometry'}->{'location'}->{'lat'};
    $long = $json->{'results'}[0]->{'geometry'}->{'location'}->{'lng'};
    return $lat.','.$long;
}
```

Comment: hi, i wanna ask if i use this code in php without getting an API key, is it ok?

Comment: no it will not work.you need to use api for getting result

Comment: Thanks for this! Searched more than hour for working code. this works for me perfectly.

Comment: `$region` is undefined.

Comment: working demo thank you sir !

Comment: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

You also need a key nowadays, to find key :
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/get-api-key

Answer (score 12):

**Using** [CURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php)

```
<?php
$address = "Kathmandu, Nepal";
$url = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=".urlencode($address);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);    
$responseJson = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$response = json_decode($responseJson);

if ($response->status == 'OK') {
    $latitude = $response->results[0]->geometry->location->lat;
    $longitude = $response->results[0]->geometry->location->lng;

    echo 'Latitude: ' . $latitude;
    echo '<br />';
    echo 'Longitude: ' . $longitude;
} else {
    echo $response->status;
    var_dump($response);
}    
?>
```

Comment: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

You also need a key nowadays, to find key :
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/get-api-key

Comment: The file_get_contents() method no longer seems to work at all for me. Replaced it with this CURL solution and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 5):

I tried above solutions but none was working then i tried to fix on my own so below is the correct code:

```
    $going=$this->input->post('going');

    $address =$going; // Google HQ
    $prepAddr = str_replace(' ','+',$address);
    $apiKey = 'Add your API Key'; // Google maps now requires an API key.

    $geocode=file_get_contents('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json? 
   address='.urlencode($address).'&sensor=false&key='.$apiKey);

    //print_r($geocode);

    $output= json_decode($geocode);
    $latitude = $output->results[0]->geometry->location->lat;
    $longitude = $output->results[0]->geometry->location->lng;
```

Comment: This is the more acceptable answer in 2020

Comment: Don't need the going stuff, that seems to be specific to @FahadKhan's scenario.

Answer (score 2):

Try this for getting the address:

```html
<?
function getaddress($lat, $lng)
{
  $url = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=' . trim($lat) . ',' . trim($lng) . '&sensor=false';
  $json = @file_get_contents($url);
  $data = json_decode($json);
  $status = $data->status;
  if ($status == "OK")
    return $data->results[0]->formatted_address;
  else
    return false;
}


$lat = 26.754347; //latitude
$lng = 81.001640; //longitude
$address = getaddress($lat, $lng);
if ($address) {
  echo $address;
} else {
  echo "Not found";
}

?>
```

Comment: does the exact opposite.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php 
// We define our address
$address = 'Indore, MP 452001';
echo"<PRE>";
print_r(get_lat_long($address));

// function to get  the address
function get_lat_long($address) {
   $array = array();
   $geo = file_get_contents('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='.urlencode($address).'&sensor=false');

   // We convert the JSON to an array
   $geo = json_decode($geo, true);

   // If everything is cool
   if ($geo['status'] = 'OK') {
      $latitude = $geo['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lat'];
      $longitude = $geo['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lng'];
      $array = array('lat'=> $latitude ,'lng'=>$longitude);
   }

   return $array;
}
```

Comment: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

You also need a key nowadays, to find key :
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/get-api-key