# PHP gmaps geocode

Tags: php, google-maps, geocoding

I have next PHP code

```
 $str = $city . ', ' . $country . ', ' . $addr;
 $address = urlencode($str);
 $country = urlencode($country);
 $json = file_get_contents("https://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=$address&sensor=false&region=$country");
 $json = json_decode($json);
 $lat = $json->{'results'}[0]->{'geometry'}->{'location'}->{'lat'};
 $long = $json->{'results'}[0]->{'geometry'}->{'location'}->{'lng'};
 if ($long and $lat) {
        $sql = "`lat`='$lat',`lng`='$long',`edit_date`=NOW()";
        $up_sql = "UPDATE `user_cards` SET " . $sql . " WHERE `id`='$id'";
    }
```

This code works successfully in 90% of cases, the problem only occurs with certain addresses.

For example if $str="Bulgaria,Ravda,Emerald Beach Resort" and $country="Bulgaria", file_get_contents return NULL, but if i paste this string to maps.google.com, google succesfull find this address. Where is the mistake?

Comment: Once try: `json_decode($json, true);`

Comment: Thank you for answer.The same situation after adding true.I try to manually open the link https://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Bulgaria%2C+Ravda%2C+Emerald+Beach+Resort&sensor=false&region=Bulgaria, and see next json: {
  "results": [],
  "status": "ZERO_RESULTS"
}. Why? (

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23212681/php-get-latitude-longitude-from-an-address

Comment: adding API key to URL and activate Geocoding API, same result ..