# I want to find lat lang of a given address using mapmyindiaapi using php. Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, mapmyindia-api

I'm trying to get lat and long of a given address using mapmyindia geocode api in Php.
It's giving an error :

> Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\api2.php on
>   line 26

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<form method="post">
<input type="text" name="address">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
</html>
<?php

//Formatted address
$address = "vijay nagar,indore";
//Send request and receive json data by address
$url = "https://api.mapmyindia.com/v3?fun=geocode&lic_key = mykey &address=$address";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, 3128);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$output = json_decode($response);

echo $lat = $output->results[0]->geometry->location->lat;
echo "<br />";
echo $long = $output->results[0]->geometry->location->lng;

?>
```

Comment: What's the output from `var_dump($output)`?

Comment: Doesn't look like $output is an object.

Comment: @Jonnix It's returning NULL only

Comment: where is your API key `lic_key = mykey`. You have to generate API key and pass it in the place of  `mykey`. Then may be you got response from API.

Comment: @CodeBreaker i have placed it correctly , still its showing "Trying to get property of non-object " error

Comment: See the error is showing because you are getting nothing(null) as response.So there is something missing due to which you are not getting response.

Comment: @ANUSHKA GARG  check this may it will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23212681/php-get-latitude-longitude-from-an-address

Comment: @CodeBreaker had seen it , no help!!