# How to get latitude and longitude from an input address

Tags: php, mysql

Hi I have an address field taking address from france only.
I want that address to be stored with longitude and latitude in my database.. Is there a way to do that.. I'm trying several codes but none of them are working.

here is my code

```
<form id="contact" action="send.php" method="post"><br> 
    <h2>Formulaire de contact</h2>
    <div id="locationField" required>
        <input id="autocomplete" placeholder="Adresse"
               onFocus="geolocate()" type="text" name="address" required="required"></input>
    </div><br>
    <input type="hidden" name="latitude" id="at" placeholder="Latitude" class="form-control" required="required"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="longitude" id="lng" placeholder="Longitude" class="form-control" required="required"/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" class="button"/>

    <script>
        function initAutocomplete() {
            autocomplete = new
                    google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
                            /** @type {!HTMLInputElement}  

                             */(document.getElementById('autocomplete')),
                            {types: ['geocode'], componentRestrictions: {country: 'fr'}});

            autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', fillInAddress);
        }

        document.getElementById('latitude').value = place.geometry.location.lat();
        document.getElementById('longitude').value = place.geometry.location.lng();
    </script>

    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?input=Paris&types=geocode&key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete"
    async defer></script>
</form>

<?php
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "web_contact";

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }

    $sql = "INSERT INTO customer1(address,latitude,longitude) 

  values('" . $_POST["address"] . "','" . $_POST["latitude"] . "','" . $_POST["longitude"] . "')";

    if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
        echo "New record created successfully";
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "" . mysqli_error($conn);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please fix the formatting of the code

Comment: And remove private API key

Comment: please see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3807963/how-to-get-longitude-and-latitude-of-any-address/#14827649

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get all addresses from databases and compare it with current latitude and longitude which you got from your form.

```
function distance($a, $b)
{
    list($lat1, $lon1) = $a;
    list($lat2, $lon2) = $b;

    $theta = $lon1 - $lon2;
    $dist = sin(deg2rad($lat1)) * sin(deg2rad($lat2)) +  cos(deg2rad($lat1)) * cos(deg2rad($lat2)) * cos(deg2rad($theta));
    $dist = acos($dist);
    $dist = rad2deg($dist);
    $miles = $dist * 60 * 1.1515;
    return $miles;
}

$myAddress = array(49.648881, -103.575312);

$allAddresses = array(
    '0' => array('address_id_1','address abcd','55.645645','-42.5323'),
    '1' => array('address_id_2','second address abcd','100.645645','-402.5323')
);

$distances = array_map(function($item) use($myAddress) {
    $a = array_slice($item, -2);
    return distance($a, $myAddress);
}, $allAddresses);

asort($distances);

echo 'Closest item is: ', print_r($allAddresses[key($distances)]);
```

`'0' => array('address_id_1','address abcd','55.645645','-42.5323'),` where 55.645645 is `latitude` and -42.5323 is `longtitude`. do not swap these else result will be wrong

seems like you are stuck on this, try this and also, do share what you are trying.

Comment: I need to declare that function ?

Answer (score 2):

1. Few functions were missing
2. IDs in form were wrong

Have corrected both, please try code below:

```
<form id="contact" action="send.php" method="post"><br>
      <h2>Formulaire de contact</h2>
      <div id="locationField" required>
          <input id="autocomplete" placeholder="Adresse"
                 onFocus="geolocate()" type="text" name="address" required="required"></input>
      </div><br>
      <input name="latitude" id="latitude" placeholder="Latitude" class="form-control" required="required"/>
      <input name="longitude" id="longitude" placeholder="Longitude" class="form-control" required="required"/>
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" class="button"/>

      <script>

            // Bias the autocomplete object to the user's geographical location,
        // as supplied by the browser's 'navigator.geolocation' object.
        function geolocate() {
          if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
              var geolocation = {
                lat: position.coords.latitude,
                lng: position.coords.longitude
              };
              var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
                center: geolocation,
                radius: position.coords.accuracy
              });
              autocomplete.setBounds(circle.getBounds());
            });
          }
        }
          function initAutocomplete() {
              autocomplete = new
                      google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
                              /** @type {!HTMLInputElement}

                               */(document.getElementById('autocomplete')),
                              {types: ['geocode'], componentRestrictions: {country: 'fr'}});

              autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', fillInAddress);
          }
          function fillInAddress() {
            var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
            console.log(place);
          document.getElementById('latitude').value = place.geometry.location.lat();
          document.getElementById('longitude').value = place.geometry.location.lng();
        }
      </script>

      <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?input=Paris&types=geocode&key=AIzaSyBJCSjFGcsFkG5Zy7k3Ph6ArHv6EoWSxpk&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete"
      async defer></script>
  </form>

  <?php
  if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
      $servername = "localhost";
      $username = "root";
      $password = "";
      $dbname = "web_contact";

      // Create connection
      $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

      if ($conn->connect_error) {
          die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
      }

      $sql = "INSERT INTO customer1(address,latitude,longitude)

    values('" . $_POST["address"] . "','" . $_POST["latitude"] . "','" . $_POST["longitude"] . "')";

      if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
          echo "New record created successfully";
      } else {
          echo "Error: " . $sql . "" . mysqli_error($conn);
      }
  }
  ?>
```

Also please do read: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform

Comment: Thank you soo much  #Anushil Nandan its working.. If I need to calculate distance from this address to that from a table address , I just have to work with the longitude and latitude?

Comment: you can use http://www.geodatasource.com/developers/php to find distance between two lat/long points. Here I am assuming that addresses stored in db have lat/long

Comment: How to calculate distance from database

Comment: there is no mysql function that i know of. you can google though. please tell the use case please

Comment: From my previous code, how do i use the following code from this url:http://tutorialswebsite.com/distance-calculator-two-places-using-google-map-api-php/  to calculate distance from two address..The input address is stored in table customer1 and i have another table shop.. how to calculate distance from these two address???

Comment: can you please share your table structure

Comment: Table customer1  {id int, address varchar(150), latitude(float), longitude(float)}         Table shop { id int, name varchar(50), address varchar(100), latitude float, longitude float}

Comment: you can fetch latitude, longitude from both customer1 and shop. once you have both you can use http://www.geodatasource.com/developers/php to find the distance. hope this makes it clear. in case you are wondering about query here you go:

select latitude,longitude from customer1
select latitude,longitude from shop

Comment: you mean it has to be this?   

$result2 = mysql_query("SELECT latitude, longitude from shop") or die(mysql_error());
while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array( $result2 )) {
         $lon=$row2['lon'];
         $lat=$row2['lat'];
     }

$result = mysql_query("SELECT latitude, longitude from customer1") or die(mysql_error());  
    $distance = 0; // accumulate the distance
  
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result )) {
         $lon2a=$lon2;
         $lat2a=$lat2;
         $lon1=$row['lon1'];
         $lat1=$row['lat1'];
         $lon2=$row['lon2'];
         $lat2=$row['lat2'];

Comment: something like: 
$result2 = mysql_query("SELECT latitude, longitude from shop") or die(mysql_error()); while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array( $result2 )) { $lon=$row2['longitude']; $lat=$row2['latitude']; } $result = mysql_query("SELECT latitude, longitude from customer1") or die(mysql_error());


you see what's wrong with your query? you are using SELECT latitude, longitude from shop, so mysql will return results in latitude and longitude variables, but while looping in while you are using $lon=$row2['lon'] which does not exist and it will give error.

Comment: i have corrected it but it gives me errors : undefined index, variable and cannot declare distance(), I want to get the closest address but it gives me  some numbers

Answer (score 1):

Sir, you need get info from here http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Paris. I use 'address' instead of 'input'.

If you work only with Paris addresses, you need to do like this
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Marais,Paris