# Best place to store google maps data

Tags: database, api, google-maps

I am in the process of writing a website where users can create their own google maps data like circling things and putting markers on a map.
What would be the best way to store the data for each user? Im thinking in a database as an array. Can anyone else think of a better more efficient way?

What I am asking (as apparently the question is unclear), is: Can I store lat and long data in a database to then load this data on to a GMap without violating GMaps terms. Or is there a more efficient way of storing the data.

Comment: Maybe this is an approach: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31487043/save-map-instance-outside-of-google-maps/31501130#31501130

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Google doesn't appear to have this restriction that you speak of. The Google Geocoding API website actually suggests caching or storing the content to reduce hits to their servers and improve performance.

As far as addresses go, your users are entering them, so you can store the addresses. The latitudes/longitudes can be retrieved from the Google Maps API service using those addresses.

It's okay to cache the results, so you'll only need to really look them up during the first search."

You can read more here:

[Maps API, storing data, how to without violating terms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4870653/maps-api-storing-data-how-to-without-violating-terms)

Comment: Thanks for this. I did come across this article but it seemed to have conflicting views so I wasnt sure. It seems to me that they are talking about the not storing the imagery when saving data to a database (as this would breach copyright)

Comment: ***It's okay to cache the results, so you'll only need to really look them up during the first search.*** :  caching doesn't mean permanent storage, the documentation clearly says *"store your results in a **temporary** cache"* (which means, based on the Terms of Service: not longer than 30 days). After this period the data must be deleted (of course you may request them again to store them for 30 days, but the issue: then you would  do it on serverside, where you may hit the quota very quick )