# `latitude` and `longitude` with PHP & MySQL

Tags: php, geolocation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to obtain longitude and latitude for a street address programmatically (and legally)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158474/how-to-obtain-longitude-and-latitude-for-a-street-address-programmatically-and-l)

I want to get the `latitude` and `longitude` for an address! I found a site use it in this way:

**Image:**
You can put an address directly or click on the map:

[image]
**EDIT 1:**

Questions:

1. How to display map for a getting latitude and longitude?

**EDIT 2:**
assuming I have:

*`Latitude 37.77618`
 
`Longitude-122.42632`*

2. How to display the map with a marker for those data

Comment: Yea, Google Maps. It doesn't have much to do with PHP/MySQL, even if you'll use those technologies to store a result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Documentation: [Google Maps API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/#PlaceSearches)

> The Places API provides two types of
>   searches: Place Searches, which return
>   a list of Places that are near a
>   user's provided location; and Place
>   Details, which returns more detailed
>   information about a specific location.

Comment: How to get `latitude ` and `longitude` with Place Details

Comment: Read them in answer of API (JSON or XML).

Comment: Thank you OZ_. Now If I have those data how can I display a map with a marker.