# Obtain latitude and longitude from address without the use of Google API

Tags: r, geocoding

I am currently working on a large population-based database where it is required that I compute the distance between two addresses for each individual. My first train of thought was to obtain the latitude and longitude representing each address and then compute the distance. I used Google API's to obtain the latitude and longitude for these addresses via various packages in R (e.g. dismo). However Google has a restriction of 2500 requests in a 24hr period. I have about 300,000 addresses and by running 2,500/day, I will not be able to meet the deadline.

Would anyone have suggestions regarding other API's I could use to obtain the latitude and longitude using R?

Thank you.

Answer (score 15):

I would recommend that you try the `RDSTK` package which interfaces with the [Data Science Toolkit](http://www.datasciencetoolkit.org). It is available on `github`.

EDIT. To compute the Road Distance, I would recommend the [Mapquest Directions API](http://www.mapquestapi.com/directions/), which appears to have no preset limits as per this [link](http://developer.mapquest.com/web/tools/getting-started/terms-overview). Let me know how it goes.

Comment: +1. Thank you @Ramnath. This website is immensely helpful. I will try this out.

Comment: Would you have suggestions for computing the 'road' distance between two addresses as Google does?

Comment: Thank you. I guess I will need to learn how to use javascript from within R to call this function.

Comment: you may not need to use javascript. if you look at the code, i think you can construct the URL using the coordinates, and use a package like `RCurl` to send a `GET/POST` request to fetch the desired data.

Answer (score 5):

What you are doing is called "geocoding". Knowing that will greatly improve your ability to search for more info :) You may have already known that since you tagged the question properly, but I wanted to make sure.

Here's a really good [previous Stack Overflow question,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158474/how-to-obtain-longitude-and-latitude-for-a-street-address-programmatically-and) albeit not R specific.

Comment: Thank you @JD Long. I do realize that the specific term is geocoding, hence the tag attached to my question. The link you sent does have a lot of resources. I will check them out for any R specific solutions.

Answer (score 2):

More options:

- The [`geonames` package](http://geonames.r-forge.r-project.org/) to retrieve information from the [geonames](http://geonames.org) service.
- The `osmar` package to use the API of [openstreetmap](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/API_v0.6).

Besides, the `gdistance` package is useful for distance calculations on geographical grids.