# How can I get latitude and longitude from an address with r?

Tags: r, geolocation

Please. I need an function in r to get latitude and longitude from an specific address.

My addresses are peruavian. 
For example:

1. Jirón Cuzco 423, Magdalena del Mar
2. Av Nicolás Arriola 500, La Victoria

Thanks!!

Comment: hope this link help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9068941/obtain-latitude-and-longitude-from-address-without-the-use-of-google-api

Answer (score 9):

`geocode` from the `ggmap` package will do the trick:

```
library(ggmap)
locs <- c('Jiron Cuzco 423, Magdalena del Mar', 'Av Nicolas Arriola 500, La Victoria')
geocode(locs)
```

Output:

```
        lon      lat
1 -77.07008 -12.0894
2 -77.01523 -12.0856
```

Comment: Hi. I tried it. but I get this:  lon lat
1  NA  NA
2  NA  NA

Comment: Seems to be a problem with the acute accents. I edited the locations, should work now

Comment: Requires an API key now