# How can I get latitude and longitude for a city?

Tags: geoip

I downloaded related csv file from [MaxMind](http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoip2/geolite2/), but I found there are only latitude longitude for a combination of zip code and city, is it possible to get latitude and longitude of the city only?

Comment: you should check to see if MaxMind has a download at the city grain rather than the zip code grain

Comment: Thanks, but I cannot find it, they only provide the one for zip code and city.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few solutions to your problem, none are quite that easy I am afraid. While there might be a better solution, I will try to make this work with what you have.

First, you have two options. Either you pre-process the file you have and add city name, respectively replace the postal codes, or you can issue queries as you need them. There are two web services I found with a simple search (there might be more) that allow you to resolve your ZIP codes: [Ziptastic](http://daspecster.github.io/ziptastic/) and [Free Zip Code Web Services](http://www.zipwise.com/webservices/). With the limited information you provided, I hope these are able to suit your needs.

However, there is an easier solution. You could use the Google Maps API which provide a web service to resolve the kind of request you would want to have resolved. Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158474/how-to-obtain-longitude-and-latitude-for-a-street-address-programmatically-and).

Comment: Another option is [GeoNames](http://www.geonames.org/). They have a free CSV as well as a web service.