# How to get Latitude and Longitude on tomcat 7 and webservice in java?

Tags: java, tomcat7

How to get Latitude and Longitude for particular city or street or location from server side in java.

Comment: You may request from a web service for that information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/158474/how-to-obtain-longitude-and-latitude-for-a-street-address-programmatically-and

Answer (score 0):

You should use any location library or api.

For example :

- https://code.google.com/p/geocoder-java/
- http://jgeocoder.sourceforge.net/

A simple google request could have answered this.

Answer (score 0):

This is called `Geocoding`, and requires matching a place name up to a latitude and longitude.

You can either code a known list of place name/lat-lons into your app, read them in at runtime and search through them when required, or you can use an online **Geocoding service such as this one from Yahoo, or this one from Google.**

**API :**
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/