# Better free option for google maps geocode

Tags: google-maps, yahoo, bing, geocode

I'm using google maps to geocode. But I have 280k address to geocode, I would like to know a better option for this.
Thank you.

I looked for Bing and Yahoo! tutorial to make the geocoder, but nothing was found, only plotting tutorials.

Comment: Explain better, "but nothing was found", Who found nothing, the geocoder, or you? You looked for a turtorial and found it, fine, whats your question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5133927/finding-latitude-and-longitude-of-many-places-once/5134268#5134268

Answer (score 0):

Bing Maps has a couple of different options for geocoding data. There is a lot of information out there on this as well.

The batch geocoder in Bing Maps allows licensed customers to geocode up to 25 files of 200,000 addresses a day. Unlicensed customers are limited to 50 addresses per file. Documentation: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg585136.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701733.aspx

Bing Maps also has an on-demand REST geocoding service which can geocode one address at a time. Here is some documentation:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701715.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj819168.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj870778.aspx

http://blogs.bing.com/maps/2013/02/14/bing-maps-rest-service-tips-tricks/

All this said, it should be noted that there are restrictions around geocodes with most mapping platforms. Generally they can not be used with competing mapping platforms. i.e. Data geocoded by Bing Maps cannot not be used in a Google Maps application.