# Google maps api v3, query limit exceeded more then 72 hours ago

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I need to know how to reset the query limit for the Google Maps API v3. I know that I exceeded it more than three days ago, but it has not reset and I am still hitting it if I send more then 5 requests. How do I restore it completely to be able to get that 2500 (or whatever the request limit is) again?

I need to geocode some addresses and put them (lat, lon) into a database. I have done so far 2500 addresses. I need to do another 1000 and then it will be just one request on page load.

Comment: "If you continue to exceed this limit, your access to the Geocoding API may be blocked"... did you only hit the limit once, or many times?

Comment: I think it was just once

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [Google Geocoding API documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/#Limits), there are actually two limits. First of all, there is the 2,500 request per day limit, which you say you triggered a few days ago. However, there is also a separate *rate limit*, which is probably what you are hitting here.

The rate limit will prevent you from making many successive geocoding requests in a short time, which it seems is what you're trying to do. There is no way around this, since making 1,000 requests on a single pageload is not the intended use of the Google Geocoding API.

Additional, according to Google:

> **Note**: the Geocoding API may only be used in conjunction with a Google map; geocoding results without displaying them on a map is prohibited. For complete details on allowed usage, consult the [Maps API Terms of Service License Restrictions](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/terms.html#section_10_12).

This probably means that your overall plan to use the Google geocoder and store the results in a database is a violation of Google's terms of service.

Comment: I was not able to think of other way to use geolocation for 5000 markers every request, so i stored them and just just putted them on the google map by one request of geolocation. hmmm ... fcuk,, what to do what to do ...

Comment: I mean how it is possible then to do it ? to upgrade to premium of google maps ? to use different domain and api key? :D (solution is not live it is just some test site for university)..

Comment: If you look at section 10.1.3 of their terms, they clearly prohibit bulk geocoding, pre-fetching, and storage. However, you could try contacting Google for a premium account and get specific provisions waived. Your mileage will obviously vary.

Comment: Personally, I would use a different geocoding service that is open to this sort of usage. MapQuest has a couple API's for this. Nominatim (http://developer.mapquest.com/web/products/open/nominatim) is the completely open one, and the licensed Geocoding API (http://developer.mapquest.com/web/products/dev-services/geocoding-ws) is available for community use as well. Both of them support bulk geocoding.

Comment: hmm i will be hard for me , and very time consumption to find out everything in this new service, maybe you have some kind of example how to get lat and lng from address by geocoding service you suggested ? i would be very appreciated.

Comment: I have tried to look at examples of that page but it has a lot of unnecessary code and etc. what i need is just function that i pass address to and get lat and lng inside it, google maps api seems to be more easier to understand then this. Can you give me some example of your ? :D thatnks

Comment: There are number of general samples at http://www.mapquestapi.com/geocoding/. However, I'm not an expert in the language I believe you're using (PHP?), so I can't provide you with any specific code for that. You may want to open a new question along the lines of "How do I do bulk geocoding against the MapQuest geocoder using PHP?", or something similar. Here is a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/396819/geocode-multiple-addresses

Answer (score 1):

If (and only if) you are going to show the results & marker on a Google Map (required by ToS), then these articles would probably help you:

1. [Geocoding Strategies](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/articles/geocodestrat.html) to make the right decision as to whether you need to use PHP (server-side) or JavaScript (client-side). It sounds like you're right to use PHP.
2. [Geocoding Addresses with PHP/MySQL](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/articles/phpsqlgeocode.html) to do the batch geocoding, provided your use case complies with the [Terms of Use](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/terms.html) ;) -- mind the paragraph about [Timing the Geocode Requests](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/articles/phpsqlgeocode.html#geocodephp) as Rohan points out your issue is likely that you're sending requests too fast.