# Any other geocoding service that would allow me to get lat and lng from address for 1000 requests just once?

Tags: php, javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geocoding

Any other geocoding service that would allow me to get lat and lng from address for 1000 requests just once ?

I can't ues Google Maps API. I need to use it freely and import lat and lng values into my database for 1000 addresses.
If anyone knows such services, could someone provide me an code example of getting such values ?

For example google maps api uses this one :

```
geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address }, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        var value1    = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
        var value2    = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
..
```

I need the same but with different geocoding service ? Please help me with such code and service thank you.

Comment: Why not just split your whole file (e.g. 1000 addresses) into pieces of 250 and process them like that? Just select 250 addresses without LAT/LNG from your database and process. And then give the script 5 minutes rest or something. That's how I do that and it works great. Then just use the data from your own database when working with it in JavaScript (e.g. through JSON).

Comment: Is 1,000 a problem? [The docs say](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/#Limits) "Use of the Google Geocoding API is subject to a query limit of 2,500 geolocation requests per day."

Comment: Don't repeat [your errors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8983814/google-maps-api-v3-query-limit-exceeded-more-then-72-hours-ago) :)

Comment: Why do you "need to use it freely"? If you really have that many addresses to look up regularly, it sounds like the level of usage that you should be paying for. On the other hand, if you only need to look these up one time then the rate limit shouldn't affect you, even if it takes a couple of days, right?

Answer (score -1):

I needed to do the same thing I while ago and used the google local search API http://wheresrhys.co.uk/2009/08/geocoding-in-the-uk/. The API may have a changed a little since then but it should basically still work.