# How to convert Address to Latitude and Longitude in iPhone Developement

Tags: iphone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to convert an address to a latitude/longitude?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98449/how-to-convert-an-address-to-a-latitude-longitude)

Anyone know how to convert address to Latitude and Longitude in iPhone Developement? I am trying to build an app that users can search address and shows on google map. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You Gould use cloud made for that - just on example.
This article http://blog.cloudmade.com/2009/06/12/how-to-get-forward-geocoding-in-iphone-mapkit/
Should help you