# How to get the latitude and longitude from address with out using google maps in Xcode,iPhone

Tags: ios, maps, latitude-longitude

Please tell me how to get the location latitude and longitude from the address with out using google maps.Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/98449/how-to-convert-an-address-to-a-latitude-longitude

Comment: Have you done any research on this yourself?

Answer (score 1):

How about trying [Yahoo! Maps Web Services - Geocoding API](http://developer.yahoo.com/maps/rest/V1/geocode.html)

After obtaining the app id, with a get request like below

```
http://local.yahooapis.com/MapsService/V1/geocode?appid=YD-9G7bey8_JXxQP6rxl.fBFGgCdNjoDMACQA--&street=701+First+Ave&city=Sunnyvale&state=CA
```

You get a xml response like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <ResultSet xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns="urn:yahoo:maps"
  xsi:schemaLocation="urn:yahoo:maps    
 http://local.yahooapis.com/MapsService/V1/GeocodeResponse.xsd">
 <Result precision="address">
  <Latitude>37.416384</Latitude>
  <Longitude>-122.024853</Longitude>
  <Address>701 FIRST AVE</Address>
   <City>SUNNYVALE</City>
   <State>CA</State>
   <Zip>94089-1019</Zip>
   <Country>US</Country>
  </Result>
 </ResultSet>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [CLLocation?](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocation_Class/CLLocation/CLLocation.html)

Comment: I tried using CLGeocoder and it displays the location in map view.but I need to display the route directions from start point to end point in Map view.Can you give me any idea how to display with out using google maps.