# append long and lat to an address table in Excel

Tags: excel, latitude-longitude

I have an excel table that has about couple of thousand business address, broken down component by component - street number, street name, suburb, city and postcode.

As I'm developing an android app that makes use of this data, I need to append longitude and latitude to this data & was wondering if I can do this within Excel itself?

Many thanks

Comment: What is your question exactly? You want to get the longitude and latitude from the street number, postcode ... or you already know how to get these and only want to know how to implement it? If that the first one, you might want to take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/98449/how-to-convert-an-address-to-a-latitude-longitude?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: The Google Geocoding API can be used from an Excel macro as described here: http://policeanalyst.com/using-the-google-geocoding-api-in-excel/