# How to calculate shipping charges

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

How to calculate the total amount (product amount + shipping charge) by calculating the distance?

Comment: calculate the distance? create your own shipment process, or if u r in USA, use USPS

Comment: It's depend on how you will process shipment. 

1. If you use shipping method like USPS or UPS or others, at first check do they have API to calculate shipping fee

2. You create a record that stores shipping fee

Feel free to ask me more details.

Comment: i am in india  the shipment by post

Comment: @ Muhammed Imran Hussain :- (second method),how to create the record of shipping fee!!

Comment: how to create the record of shipping fee!

Comment: In one of my project I required to calculate flat shipping fee by weight and size. So I just created record for example 0-5kg $100, 6-10kg $200 and based on the weight the calculation done. For your case if you require to manually create record. # 1. At first get the fees from your shipping method for example Indian Post. Then #2. add fees in records by distance #3 calculate geo distance and shipping fee. If you store city in your order there are lot of apis to get the lat,lang

Comment: This is very old post but might be helpful for you to get latitude and longitude: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/98449/how-to-convert-an-address-to-a-latitude-longitude

Comment: I am Mr. not Mrs :)

Comment: sry mr Muhammed Imran Hussain

Comment: <?php foreach($tips -> result() as $row ){
$k=0;
?>
<li class="<?php if(($k++)%2==1) echo "grey-box"; else echo "white-box"; ?>">
 
  <div class="imgt-1"><img src="<?php echo base_url();?>resources/images/123.png" width="25px" height="25px"></div>
  <div class="text" style="padding-left:15px;"><?php  echo $row->tips_desc;?></div>
  </li>

<?php }?>

Comment: this is not working in codeignier